# Why does this function give a parse error in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I was playing with ghci and I can't figure out why the following gives me a parse error:

```
*Test> break (\x -> x == '\r') "foobar"

<interactive>:52:37:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
*Test>
```

If I bind it to a variable it works

```
*Test> z = break (\x -> x == '\r') "foobar"
*Test> z
("foobar","")
```

And if I apply it in parenthesis it also works

```
*Test> (break (\x -> x == '\r') "foobar")
("foobar","")
```

Doing a similar function that accepts a lambda and a list I have no problems

```
*Test> map (\x -> '\r') "foobar"
"\r\r\r\r\r\r"
```

What am I missing here? It's not stopping me from doing anything but I'd like to understand why ghci is unhappy

Comment: What version of ghci are you using? It seems to work for me in 7.4.1.

Comment: must be your ghci, for me it works too

Comment: weird, @sth I'm using ghci version 7.6.3 on windows

Comment: @devshorts I'm using 7.6.3 on win7 and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @bheklilr, very weird. Ok well it must be something environmental then. Thanks everyone. At least I'm not crazy!

Comment: That's a crazy GHCi, allowing variable bindings without using 'let'

Comment: @bennofs is that not a normal thing? I don't know, I'm pretty new to haskell.

Comment: If I run `:break (\x -> x == '\r') "foobar"`, I get a similar error (`:break` is a ghci command for adding breakpoints), so maybe your ghci config is adding the colon automatically? Try running ghci with `ghci -ignore-dot-ghci`, and trying again. If that fixes the problem, then check your [ghci config file](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) to see what you have.

Comment: @DavidMiani, interesting. It maybe related to the sublimeREPL that I am using. If I run it in regular ghci it worked fine.  I'll lodge a bug with them. I just tried the following `break (\x -> x=='\r') "foobar"` which worked. The difference is a space between the equals and the carriage return.  Anyways, sounds like its a bug with them and not anything that I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: try to retype it manually, not copy-paste. It is a valid code